# Imaginary numbers in PCA output

Tags: correlation, pca, covariance

Using PCA manually on correlation matrix, I'm getting imaginary numbers in both eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Is this expected behavior?

I understand that when interpreting a matrix as a linear transformation, the eigenvectors can be thought of as the "principal effects" of the transformation. The 'limit', one might say, is when the transformation is recursively applied to some arbitrary input vector for an infinite number of iterations and this vector is pulled into the span of the leading eigenvector (the other effects are simply washed out.)

I use this mental framework as it helps me make sense of rotational matrices. There is no principal effect; the arbitrary vector is rotated infinitely but never converges on a real span (hence the imaginary numbers.)

So I'm left wondering, if the output of PCA (using correlation matrix) has imaginary numbers in its eigenvectors and eigenvalues then it might be a rotational matrix - aka no span convergence. In this light, I'm doubtful that such eigenvectors can be of any use in some downstream task and simply removing the imaginary numbers sounds like a perilous choice.

Response to comments/answers:

I checked for symmetry using

```
def check_symmetric(a, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08):
    return np.allclose(a, a.T, rtol=rtol, atol=atol)

check_symmetric(correlation_matrix)
```

The response was true. Additionally, I used `np.corrcoef` for correlation matrix and `numpy.linalg.eig` for eigen decomposition.

Having verified these conditions, I wonder what else might be wrong...

One other side note is that the minimum correlation is 0.58, which seems a bit high, perhaps pointing to an issue with the input data? (The max correlation is of course 1.0)

Comment: Did you call a function that assumes the correlation matrix is symmetric (e.g. `numpy.linalg.eigh` vs `numpy.linalg.eig`)?

Comment: I used the latter - `numpy.linalg.eig` but I believe that a correlation matrix should always be symmetric, no?

Comment: Likewise, used `np.corrcoef` for correlation matrix

Comment: eig will give imaginary outputs to large symmetric matrices because of numerical error. This is actually part of the reason why eigh exists. (in R, it is the same function eigen in either case, but set the argument "symmetric" to TRUE).

Comment: @JohnMadden - oh thank you! I was unaware of the difference. Indeed, `eigh` produces all real outputs.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example -- or at least tell us what the eigenvalues are that you found!  It sounds like you might just be either misreading the output or are focusing on an imaginary part that differs from zero by floating point roundoff.

Comment: @JohnMadden - `eigh` was exactly what I needed, thanks! Note, there was some very small but non-zero imaginary numbers in the `eig` solution but this was cleared up by `eigh`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A correlation matrix is symmetrical and hence all the eigenvalues are real.

I would verify a few things:

- I would check if the correlation matrix is indeed a symmetric matrix.
- Is the magnitude large for the imaginary part? If it is small, it is likely due to numerical issue.

Comment: Added some context to the question prompt, including, yes the matrix is symmetric. Additionally, the max Eigenvalue is `123.86+0j` - which seems a bit large to your second question. @siong-thye-goh

Comment: @jbuddy_13, the maginutde of the imaginary part of your reported eigenvalue is numerically 0.

Comment: @jbuddy_13 `123.86+0j` means `123.86` (a real number) plus `0j` (zero imaginary number). So it's equivalent to `123.86` (a real number). So there is no imaginary number in that eigenvalue.